# Volley Servor Error for a particular type of data

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking

I am using Volley POST request.Actually I am reading all the sms from the user's phone and sending it to back-end.**The JSON required by back-end and the JSON which I am posting are all correct and verified.**When I filter the body by **"INR"** in the below code the Status is OK 200.But its giving server error for no filter which is the main work:

```
 public JSONObject fetchInbox() throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<Sms> sms = new ArrayList();
    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"address","_id","_id","body","date"}, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    JSONArray smsarray=new JSONArray();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String address = cursor.getString(0);
        String foldername="smsbox";
        String id=cursor.getString(1);
        String body = cursor.getString(3);
        long datex= Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4));
        Pattern p= Pattern.compile("\\s");
        String[] datearray=p.split(convertFromUnix(datex));
        String date=datearray[0]+","+datearray[1]+" "+datearray[2]+","+datearray[5];
        int lat=0;
        int longt=0;
        JSONObject smsObject=new JSONObject();
        smsObject.put("_address",address);
        smsObject.put("_folderName",foldername);
        smsObject.put("_id",id);
        smsObject.put("_msg",body);
        smsObject.put("_time",String.valueOf(datex));
        smsObject.put("lat",lat);
        smsObject.put("longt",longt);
        if(body.contains("INR")){
            smsarray.put(smsObject);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    JSONObject studentsObj = new JSONObject();
    studentsObj.put("messages", smsarray);
    return studentsObj;
}
```

**But after removing the "INR" filter the volley is giving Server Error**.What could be the problem?

Here is the code to send JSON via volley:

```
private void sendJson(JSONObject jsondata) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String URL = tokenurl;
    final String requestBody = jsondata.toString();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.e("Ff", "onResponse: " + response.toString());
            Log.e("F", "###### sent");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progs.setMessage("Error in Syncing due to : " + error.toString() + "\n" + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
            Log.e("VOLLEY12", error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progs.setMessage("Synced");
                        progs.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                String jsonv = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                Log.e("tt", " ====================================" + jsonv);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String responseString = "";
            if (response != null) {
                responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
            }
            return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getmInstance(this).addToReqQue(stringRequest);
}
```

**Here is the Error 500 when I post all msgs without filter.**

```
 {"messages":[{"_address":"+919950853941","_folderName":"smsbox","_id":"384","_msg":"Recharge successful for Rs 70.00 .Talktime Credited: Rs 63.70， Processing Fee: Rs 3.00， Service Tax: Rs  3.30. Current Balance: Rs 63.35. Validity :7-July-15","_time":"1431678589000","lat":0,"longt":0},{"_address":"+919928655851","_folderName":"smsbox","_id":"381","_msg":"Recharge successful for Rs 70.00 .Talktime Credited: Rs 63.70， Processing Fee: Rs 3.00， Service Tax: Rs  3.30. Current Balance: Rs 63.35. Validity :7-July-15","_time":"1431678589000","lat":0,"longt":0}]}
```

01-30 00:53:56.648 10053-10592/finlit.smstesting E/Volley: [57351] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://jake.pythonanywhere.com/api/user/2/

1. 30 00:53:56.692 10053-10053/finlit.smstesting E/VOLLEY12: com.android.volley.ServerError

**Here is the log when it runs with INR filter**

```
{"messages":[{"_address":"+918209883159","_folderName":"smsbox","_id":"4003","_msg":"Debited of INR 3000 Ac XXX000000 drawn th ATM ID:000000         on 12\/10 at 11:14:02.Cl Bal: 1545.00 CR. Use INDIAN BANK ATM to avoid charges - Indian Bank","_time":"1514208973874","lat":0,"longt":0},{"_address":"+918209883159","_folderName":"smsbox","_id":"4002","_msg":"Withdrawal of INR 600 Ac XXX000000 drawn th ATM ID:000000         on 12\/10 at 11:14:02.Cl Bal: 1545.00 CR. Use  ATM to avoid charges - Indian Bank","_time":"1514208924240","lat":0,"longt":0},{"_address":"+918209883159","_folderName":"smsbox","_id":"3733","_msg":"Withdrawal of INR 1,000 Ac XXX000000 drawn th ATM ID:000000         on 12\/10 at 11:14:02.Cl Bal: 1545.00 CR. Use INDIAN BANK ATM to avoid charges - Indian Bank","_time":"1508137822369","lat":0,"longt":0},{"_address":"+918209883159","_folderName":"smsbox","_id":"3732","_msg":"Withdrawal of INR 1,000 Ac XXX000000 drawn th ATM ID:000000         on 12\/10 at 11:14:02.Cl Bal: 1545.00 CR. Use INDIAN BANK ATM to avoid charges - Indian Bank","_time":"1508082024771","lat":0,"longt":0},{"_address":"+918209883159","_folderName":"smsbox","_id":"3731","_msg":"Withdrawal of INR 1,000 Ac XXX000000 drawn th ATM ID:000000         on 12\/10 at 11:14:02.Cl Bal: 175.00 CR. Use INDIAN BANK ATM to avoid charges - Indian Bank","_time":"1508081984480","lat":0,"longt":0}]}
01-30 01:12:20.981 29131-29131/finlit.smstesting E/Ff: onResponse: 200
```

01-30 01:12:20.981 29131-29131/finlit.smstesting E/F: ###### sent

Comment: With a 500 (internal server error), you should check the server logs on the backend.

Comment: But for server error it should also give errors with INR filter

Comment: No it shouldn't.  So, what do you find in the server logs?